# Deduction from two strict inequalities

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0<a<b<1$ and $0<c<1<d<2$.

I deduce:

$$\frac{d}{a}>\frac{c}{b}.$$

My question:

Is there anything I can say about a relationship between $ad$ and $bc$? For example:

$$ad <\text{or} >bc?$$

Or is anything possible between these two quantities?

Comment: Nothing can be comented on the relationship.You can just fix any three variables and always find  a value for the fourth variable that satisfies any inequality or equality.

Comment: @RamanujanXV Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you only know the relative size of $d$ relative to $a$ and $c$ to $b$.

For example:

Let $d=kn,a=k$ for some $k,n>0$ then $ad=k^2n, \frac{d}{a} = k\;\; \forall n$

Similarly,

Let $c=jm,a=j$ for some $j,m>0$ then $cb=j^2m, \frac{c}{b} = j\;\; \forall n$

Therefore, knowing $\frac{d}{a} > \frac{c}{b}$ only implies $k>j$ but we can set $m,n$ such that $ad>bc$ or $ad < bc$, so it doesn't tell us anything.

Specifically, assuming $k>j$:

$$\frac{n}{m} < \frac{k^2}{j^2} \implies ad > bc$$

And similarly for $ad<bc$

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the response.